# Figures occurring after ^ and _ macros (was: LaTeX limitation?)

Tags: latex, macros, limit, undefined, figure

I've hit an annoying problem in LaTeX.  I've got a tex file of about 1000 lines.  I've already got a few figures, but when I try to add another figure, It barfs with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \sf@size \z@ \selectfont \@currbox

l.937 \begin{figure}[t]
```

If I move the figure to other parts of the file, I can get similar errors on different lines:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \sf@size \z@ \selectfont \@currbox

l.657 \paragraph
                {A Centering Algorithm}
```

If I comment out the figure, all is ok.

```
%\begin{figure}[t]
% \caption{Example decision tree, from Reiter and Dale [2000]}
% \label{fig:relation-decision-tree}
% \centering
% \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{./relation-decision-tree.eps}
%\end{figure}
```

If I keep just the begin and end like:

```
\begin{figure}%[t]
% \caption{Example decision tree, from Reiter and Dale [2000]}
% \label{fig:relation-decision-tree}
% \centering
% \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{./relation-decision-tree.eps}
\end{figure}
```

I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \sf@size \z@ \selectfont \@currbox

l.942 \end
          {figure}
```

At first, I thought maybe LaTeX has hit some limit, and I tried playing with the ulimits, but that didn't help.  Any ideas?

i've got other figures with graphics already.  my preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass[acmcsur,acmnow]{acmtrans2n}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\makecompactlist{quote*}{quote}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{ulem}
```

Comment: Not a clue. But latex had no trouble typesetting my 200+ page dissertation with scores of figures and tables and more that 100 references in six chapters and two appendicies. Mere scale usually does not phase latex.

Comment: I've encountered this error when mixing certain packages. I would suggest going through your packages one-by-one and commenting them out to see if that fixes it. Yes, this sucks.

Comment: @dmckee - nice work.  And the correct spelling is "faze".  "Phase" has to do with angular difference between the peaks of two waves, not "being bothered".

Comment: @duffymo So it is. But I'm a physicist and my fingers type the ph form automatically.

Comment: @notjim - tried that. commented out one by one. found 3 packages i'm not using (probably left over from when i was using pdflatex). still have the same problem adding another figure.  i think it might be the documentclass, and that would really suck.

Comment: Do you have a `\textsuperscript` command anywhere?

Comment: That's a strange one.  I can't quite tell from the error messages, but is it complaining about `\@currbox`?  Because that's a standard LaTeX internal macro.  The fact that you trigger the error on a `\paragraph` is suspicious as well.  You might try a binary search of your document - comment out the top/bottom halfs of it to see which one is causing the error, since it may not actually be localized to the line that generates it.  You can usually narrow it down with a bit of effort this way.

Comment: So, I thought doing a binary search would be as good as moving the figure around, but apparently it's better.  I found, not that it's a problem with `\textsuperscript`, but that it's with a ^ def I picked up from http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/SubscriptAndSuperscriptInTextMode .  The fix is to put the use of `^` in `{}`, as in I've put entire sections where I use lots of `^` and `_` in `{}`.  Hurrah!

Comment: @dmckee - a real scientist.  What was the topic for that dissertation?

Comment: @duffymo: an  experimental search for the hypothetical existence of a phenomena in post-scattering nuclear interactions called "color transparency". If you really want to know we should take it off line, but we got a beautiful, high-precision null result.

Comment: Quantum chromodynamics?  You flatter me by even proposing that we take it off-line.  I'm a mechanical engineer, not a physicist.  I learned a long time ago that there's a big difference.  You have my admiration.

Comment: @duffymo: I'm an experimenter, not a big brain: some theorist tells what the signature would be, I go find it (or not in the case of my thesis work). The admiration runs both way. My efforts sometimes requires engineering. We try, of course, but some stuff just has to be handed over to someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: @dmckee - au contraire, the "big brain" theorists are only as good as the data the experimentalist gives them.   It's hand in glove, as far as I'm concerned.  And who would dare say that the experimentalists at Brookhaven, Los Alamos, and CERN aren't big brains in their own right?  Nice work, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, not that it's a problem with `\textsuperscript`, but that it's with a ^ def I picked up from http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/SubscriptAndSuperscriptInTextMode .  The fix is to put the use of `^` in `{}`, as in I've put entire sections where I use lots of `^` and `_` in `{}`.  Hurrah!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. May I suggest that a change of question title could make this more searchable for latter users. Best if you could get some keywords from the error message *and* a reference to the "^"/"_" in there.

Comment: done.  hopefully searchable by people who made the same assumption i did, as well as people who have successfully identified the cause.

Answer (score 1):

During the end of my Master Thesis I also had the problem that after some amount of figures, I got an error without any special error message. After I read you thread, I also tried something with the packages included and in the end I was successful by taking out the \usepackage{pxfonts} and \usepackage{txfonts}. Yeah, finally.. I almost went crazy.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I Google for "latex undefined control sequence" I get [this](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/670.htm~mainFrame).

I've successfully included a graphic into LaTeX using something like this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,graphicx}

...

I just wanted to test adding an image to a \LaTeX file:

\includegraphics[scale=0.60]{basic-info.png}
```

I typeset an entire dissertation of 200 pages with lots of figures in LaTeX and didn't run into a limit like that.  I'd bet on a syntax problem first before I'd assume a size issue.

Comment: i assumed a syntax problem, but i can't imagine moving the figure to change the syntax error, nor can i imagine scale being the problem, either.  but something is wrong, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies elsewhere.  I wouldn't be the least surprised if it turned out to be the document class.  Try altering your document for `\documentclass{article}` and see where you get.  If that fixes the problem you can complain to the ACM (ROTFLMAO—I've dealth with ACM).

If that doesn't fix, the problem, slip in a `\tracingall` somewhat before the offending figure or section, put the results into http://pastebin.com/, and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Please receive the thanks of a (formerly) utterly-confounded graduate student. Quick clarification for other users:

{The quickest ^{way} to put this solution into practice is to bracket all sections of text involving the character ``\^'' as shown here.}