# \begin{figure}[H] works, but \begin{figure}[htbp] doesn't

Tags: latex

I want to insert png files into my document.

basically, like this, it works (after invoking 'float'),

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
      \includegraphics{myfigure}
    \caption{short caption}{VERY LONG FIGURE LEGEND}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

but like that, it doesn't,

```
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \begin{center}
      \includegraphics{myfigure}
    \caption{short caption}{VERY LONG FIGURE LEGEND}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

which is weird to me; obviously I invoke `\usepackage{graphicx}` as well since without that it wouldn't work in the first place. Any suggestions what the problem could be?

**UPDATED: found the solution:**

I had defined the \textsuperscript macro as in http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/SubscriptAndSuperscriptInTextMode

a fix is sketched in [Figures occurring after ^ and _ macros (was: LaTeX limitation?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497047/figures-occurring-after-and-macros-was-latex-limitation), and it seems to work for me

cheers!!

Comment: I've flagged this for migration to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Don't repost over there, since moderators will move it there. You mention it "doesn't work". What does that mean? Also, I don't see why there would be an "Undefined control sequence" in your code snippet. Rather include a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that shows your problem. This should include `\documentclass` and all the necessary packages you're loading, including [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: Nothing in your original question indicated that you were using the \textsuperscript macro. So no-one could have solved your problem. This is why it is important to have a minimal working example, as Werner points out.

Comment: point well taken, although it was difficult to anticipate from this seemingly unrelated fact -- also, I only found the other thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497047/figures-occurring-after-and-macros-was-latex-limitation) by google'ing the compiler messages I had posted ; and in that thread, people had guessed what the problem was, pretty much out of the blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**found the solution:**

I had defined the \textsuperscript macro as in http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/SubscriptAndSuperscriptInTextMode

a fix is sketched in [Figures occurring after ^ and _ macros (was: LaTeX limitation?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497047/figures-occurring-after-and-macros-was-latex-limitation) and it seems to work for me

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it here, but I think the combination `htbp` and `!` is not allowed. The `!` defines that LaTeX should listen to the given placement specifier and place the figure how you specify it. You say with `htbp!` to LaTeX something like

> Place my image here, at the top, at the bottom or on a special page. And do it all!

You should choose either `htbp` or `h!`, `t!`, `b!` or `p!`, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- I have seen htbp! used in examples before, so I think it's not the problem; also I just tried `h!`, `t!`, `b!` and `p!` with the same result as before